# Normally distributed variable with normally distributed mean.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

What the idea behind the prove of following statement?
I am pretty sure the statement it is correct.

If $X \sim N(\text{mean}_x, \text{var}_x)$ and $Y \sim N(\text{mean}_y+X, \text{var}_y)$,
then $Y \sim N(\text{mean}_x+\text{mean}_y, \text{var}_x+\text{var}_y)$

Comment: I think $Y\sim \mathcal N(\mu_y+X, \sigma_y^2)$ is not correct. X is a random variable. It cannot be a parameter-or a part of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are specifying a hierarchical model, you need to use correct and precise notation:  $$\begin{align*} X &\sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2); \\ Y \mid X &\sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_y + X, \sigma_y^2). \end{align*}$$  Without the conditional on the LHS, you are failing to distinguish the difference between the normality of the **unconditional** or **marginal** distribution of $Y$, and the normality of the **conditional** distribution of $Y$ **given** $X$.

The marginal distribution is simply $$\begin{align*} f_Y(y) &= \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) f_X(x) \, dx \\ &\propto \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(y - (\mu_y + x))^2}{2\sigma_y^2} - \frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{2\sigma_x^2} \right) \, dx. \end{align*}$$  It is up to you to compute this integral and demonstrate your understanding.

That said, if you have trouble doing the computation, then note that your model can be standardized:  $$Y \mid X = Y \mid Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_x + \mu_y + \sigma_x Z, \sigma_y^2),$$ where $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$; thus with another location-scale transformation we can look at the marginal distribution of the variable $$W = \frac{Y - (\mu_x + \mu_y)}{\sigma_y},$$ whose conditional is $$W \mid Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\sigma_x Z, 1).$$  Now this should be tractable to anyone with a knowledge of basic calculus.

Comment: I'm a bit ashamed to ask, since you say this should be tractable to anyone, but I got on my own as far as what you have before "It is up to you to compute...". The rest, I also didn't manage _with_ your answer. Could you please elaborate how to get from that integral to the definition of the normal distribution with the sum of means as the mean and the sum of variances as the variance?

Comment: The exercise it not easy to solve. See the derivations in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables at "Proof using convolutions".